# Calculate $\int\int_E e^{5x^2+2xy+y^2}dA$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, change-of-variable

How to calculate $$\int\int_E e^{5x^2+2xy+y^2}dA,$$ where $E=\{(x,y)\mid 5x^2+2xy+y^2\leq 1\}$?
 I know I have to use the change-of-variable formula by first finding the change-of-variable function $\Psi$. However, what's the function should I use? And how to deal with the annoying $xy$-term?

Comment: $5x^2+ 2xy+ y^2= 4x^2+ x^2+ 2xy+ y^2= 4x^2+ (x+ y)^2$.  Let z= x+ y and that becomes $4x^2+ z^2\le 1$, an ellipse, and its interior, in xz-space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume that the quadratic form $q(x,y)=ax^2+2bxy+cy^2$, associated to the matrix $Q=\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ b & c \end{pmatrix}$ is positive definite, i.e. $a>0$ and $ac>b^2$ (Sylvester's criterion). Let 
$$E_q=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: q(x,y)\leq 1\}.$$
By the spectral theorem,
$$ \iint_{E_q}e^{q(x,y)}\,dx\,dy = \iint_{\lambda_1 x^2+\lambda_2 y^2\leq 1}e^{\lambda_1 x^2+\lambda_2 y^2}\,dx\,dy $$
where $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ are the eigenvalues of $Q$. By straightforward substitutions, the RHS equals
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_1 \lambda_2}}\iint_{X^2+Y^2\leq 1}e^{X^2+Y^2}\,dX\,dY=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\det Q}}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\rho e^{\rho^2}\,d\rho\,d\theta=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{ac-b^2}}}. $$
Can you see what happens by considering $a=5$ and $b=c=1$?

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate more on the "straightforward substitutions" part?

Comment: Rescale and switch to polar coordinates.

Comment: Thank you. I think I understand the process. Use the spectrum theorem suggest a way on how to choose the "right" transformation. And after applying such transformation, the region consequently changed. A slightly generalized question: how about the integrand is not bad, but the integral region is very bad, like $\int_{\Bbb R^2}e^{-(4x^2+4xy+5y^2)}d(x,y)$? This time, is not like the original one that the region is also a somewhat "correspoding ellipse" (so the change-of-variable formula works fine.) This is a problem came from an degree exam years ago.

Comment: And by the way, the eigenvalues of the quadratic form in this post is https://imgur.com/a/GFohi, which looks very ugly, including the orthonormal eigenvectors. It seems hard to compute, is there anything wrong?

Comment: The point is that if the integration domain is sufficiently symmetric, you do not need to compute the Jordan decomposition of Q, since Q is conjugated to a diagonal matrix through an orthogonal transformation an the product of the eigenvalues equals the determinant of Q.

Comment: Hmm.. not sure I understand. I think I should post a new question, can you help me [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2631447/int-bbb-r2e-4x24xy5y2dx-y)? Thanks.