# Evaluation of an Improper Integral on $\mathbb{R^2}$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

> **Problem.** Evaluate $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(5x^2-6xy+5y^2)}dxdy$$

**My Solution**. A hint is given that "Use $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ax^2}dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}$ "

Now,

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(5x^2-6xy+5y^2)}dxdy=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-5(x-\frac{3y}{5})^2}e^{-\frac{16}{5}y^2}dxdy$

But here the range of integration is whole $\mathbb{R^2}$. I know the definition of double integral on a plane bounded region in $\mathbb{R^2}$. So How should I calculate this last integral?

Can I proceed by repeatedly integrate w.r.to $x$ and $y$ like the following:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-5(x-\frac{3y}{5})^2}e^{-\frac{16}{5}y^2}dxdy=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{16}{5}y^2}(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-5(x-\frac{3y}{5})^2}dx)dy=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{16}{5}y^2}(\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{5}})dy=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{5}}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{16/5}}=\frac{\pi}{4}$

Is this right approach? If so how?

Comment: One usually transforms $(x,y)$ to some $(u,v)$ to diagonalise the quadratic form in the exponent. Several similar questions have been asked here before including the general one.

Comment: No, you can not lose the variable $y$ upon integrating with respect to $x$, if the integral converges.

Comment: Then How should I proceed..?

Comment: Similar questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/877711/evaluate-int-infty-infty-int-infty-inftye-frac12x2-xyy, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384732/find-the-value-of-int-infty-infty-int-infty-inftye-x2xyy2.

Comment: @StubbornAtom..in that post Can you please tell me how Matthias use  the transformation $x+1/2y=x'$ while the other variable $y$ is remain unchanged....$y$ should be also changed according the transformation $x+1/2y=x'$ ..!!

Comment: @IndrajitGhosh He has used the change of variables $(x,y)\to(x',y')$ such that $x'=x-\frac{1}{2}y$ and $y'=y$, which is the same as saying $(x,y)\to(x',y)$ where $x'=x-\frac{1}{2}y$.

Comment: oh... Thank you so much..

Comment: An explicit diagonalization is not needed, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2629686/calculate-int-int-e-e5x22xyy2da/2630075#2630075 where $$\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}e^{-Q(x,y)}\,dx\,dy = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{\det M_Q}}$$ is proved only assuming that the matrix $M_Q$ (associated to the quadratic form $Q$) is positive definite. It gives that the outcome here is just $\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{5^3-3^2}}=\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
5x^2-6xy-5y^2 \equiv 8X^2+2Y^2
$$

This is obtained making a change of variables (rotation) to eliminate the cross product $x y$

now

$$
 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(5x^2-6xy+5y^2)}dxdy =  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(8X^2+2Y^2)}dXdY
$$

and then

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-8X^2}dX = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt 2}\\
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-2Y^2}dY = \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}\\
$$

hence

$$
 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(5x^2-6xy+5y^2)}dxdy =\frac{\pi}{4}
$$

Comment: Did u diagonalize the quadratic form to obtained the rotations..?

Comment: @IndrajitGhosh Yes. This is the trick.

Comment: Okay....thank you...

Comment: @IndrajitGhosh You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** With polar substitution
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(5x^2-6xy+5y^2)}dxdy=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-5r^2+3r^2\sin2\theta}\ r\ drd\theta$$
Can you proceed?

Comment: Should I repeatedly integrate w.r.to r and $\theta$ treating other variable constant??

Comment: okay I meant: $\int_{0}^{2\pi} d\theta \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-r^2(5-3sin 2\theta)}dr$

Comment: Okay thanks....

Comment: Did you use weierstrauss substitution from here?

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(5x^2-6xy+5y^2)}dxdy=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-5x^2}e^{6xy}e^{-5y^2}dxdy=\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-5x^2}dx\right)\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-5y^2}dy\right)\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{6xy}dxdy\right)=\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-5x^2}dx\right)^2 \left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{6xy}dxdy\right)$$
I think this is true, and the first integral left is easy so it would just mean solving the second. Correct me if I'm wrong.